# Woocommerce custom field on emails outputs 'Array'

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, email

I'm trying to add a custom email field in Woocommerce.

Code to add the pickup date field to checkout:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Pickup Date Field
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'gfm_pickup_date_field' );

function gfm_pickup_date_field( $checkout ) {

    // The pickup delay is the minimum number of days between when an order is placed
    // and when it can be picked up.

    $pickup_delay = gfm_get_min_pickup_delay();

    echo '<div id="gfm_pickup_date_field"><h3>' . __('Pickup') . '</h3>';

    woocommerce_form_field( 'gfm_pickup_date', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('gfm_pickup_date-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('Pickup Date'),
        'placeholder'   => __('month/day/year'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'gfm_pickup_date' ));

    echo '</div>';
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#gfm_pickup_date').datepicker({
                    dateFormat : 'mm/dd/yy',
                    minDate: {$pickup_delay}
                });
            });
            </script>";
}
```

Code to save pickup date with order:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Save Pickup Date with Order
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'gfm_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function gfm_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    // Save pickup date if user chose to pickup the order

    if (WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0] == 'local_pickup') {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'gfm_pickup_date', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gfm_pickup_date'] ) );
    }
}
```

And code to send the emails:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Add the Pickup Date to Emails
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'gfm_order_meta_keys');

function gfm_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
    $keys[] = 'gfm_pickup_date';
    return $keys;
}



  function gfm_enqueue_scripts() {

      wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.css');

      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'));

  }



  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'gfm_enqueue_scripts' );
```

When I run this code, it does the following:
[image: none]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with:

```
function gfm_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {

    $new_keys = array('Pickup date'=>'gfm_pickup_date');
    // if the action is used by another plugin, we merge keys into one array
    $keys = array_merge($keys, $new_keys);

    return $keys;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! It didn't work :P Do you know of anything else I can try with the code I've got?

Comment: I edit my answer, I confused with another action.

Comment: No luck, same output as before :P

Comment: EDIT: The 'Array' it is spitting out seems to be the get_post_meta array. I'm going to go find out if the array contains anything called gfm_pickup_date.

Comment: You will get it in the source : woocommerce/includes/class-wc-emails.php starting to line 390. I think it miss [$key]

Comment: Where would it be missing [$key] in this file?

Comment: $new_keys['gfm_pickup_date'] = array('Pickup date'=>'gfm_pickup_date');

Comment: This works! Unfortunately it turns out that sanitize_text_field( $_POST['gfm_pickup_date'] ) doesn't contain anything when the order is sent in. So the new array is still empty.

Comment: Essentially the same problem as in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297223/woocommerce-custom-field-not-saving

Comment: sanitize_text_field is maybe not the right way to sanitize a date field. Instead of this function, you can try without (!!) or with sanitize_meta(). https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_meta

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much for your time, you've been a big help!

Comment: Cool, don't forget to mark it as resolve (and an upvote is welcome too :-))

Comment: I will definitely upvote (I don't have enough rep for it to show though)